# Prove if $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$ then $T$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have seen a different answer to this so I would like to know if my approach is correct or not. If not why?
Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space, $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$

Prove if $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$ then $T$ is nilpotent

Attempt: Suppose the only eigenvalue of $T$ is $0$.

Then $V$ has a basis $v_1,...,v_m$ of generalized eigenvectors in the generalized eigenspace for $0$.

Thus $$T^{\text{dim}V}(v_i)=0 \text{ for each } i=1,...,m$$

Since $v_1,...,v_m$ is a basis of $v$, $$T^{\text{dim}V}(v)=0$$

for each $v \in V$. So $T$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Do you know Cayley Hamilton? Because you are basically saying that because every eigenvalue is a root of the characteristic polynomial, the latter is $x^n$ (plus or minus), to $T^n(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I know it says that for every linear transformation on a complex vector space with characteristic polynomial $q$,that $q(T)=0$. So you are saying this is the wrong approach?

Comment: I’m saying that you are essentially using Cayley-Hamilton without saying so, thereby making things harder. You are already using (sub silentio) that the characteristic polynomial is $x^n$ to guarantee a basis of generalized eigenvectors all associated to the eigenvalue $0$. But once you have that the characteristic polynomial is $x^n$, you are done.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin He's not really using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, nor is he actually assuming the characteristic polynomial is $x^n$. Instead he's using the theorem that guarantees the existence of a basis of generalised eigenvectors, which is used to show the existence of Jordan Normal Forms and the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. The question assumes that $0$ is the only eigenvalue, so it's perfectly reasonable to assume that each of the basis of generalised eigenvectors corresponds to the eigenvalue $0$. (Miles, the proof is correct by the way.)

Comment: @user780985: The theorem that guarantees the existence of a basis of generalized eigenvectors (and hence of a Jordan Normal Form) requires that the characteristic polynomial split. That means that the characteristic polynomial is of the form $(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$, with $a_i$ the eigenvalues (with multiplicity). That means the characteristic polynomial is $x^n$, given the assumption on eigenvalues. At this point, he can just use Cayley-Hamiton, explicitly. Invoking “there is always a basis of generalized eigenvectors” essentially invokes that the characteristic pol. is of that form.

Comment: @user780985: I did not say he was **assuming** the characteristic polynomial was $x^n$, I said he was *using* that fact (when he asserts/invokes the existence of a basis of generalized eigenvectors). Also, while Cayley-Hamilton over $\mathbb{C}$ can be proven using a basis of generalized eigenvectors, C-H holds over any field, so it does not in fact use a basis of generalized eigenvectors. Your statement that it is “used to show [...] the Cayley-Hamilton theorem” is, in fact, not true, as C-H is a statement over arbitrary fields.

Answer (score 1):

> **Lemma 1** All eigenvalues = $0$ implies strict upper-triangularity

By induction. If $V = \mathbb{C}$ then $v \neq 0 \implies T(v)= 0 \implies T = 0 $. Assume it true for $1,...,n-1$ then $T$ has all eigenvalues equal to $0$ implies there exists a non-zero $v$ such that $T(v)= 0$. Complete $v$ up to a basis $v,w_1,...,w_{n-1}$ and consider the matrix of $T$ in this new basis. We see that the first column is zero and therefore $T= \begin{pmatrix}0 &T_{1,2}  & \dots & T_{1,n} \\ 0&T_{2,2}  & \dots & T_{2,n}  \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots 
 \\ 0 &T_{n,2} & \dots &  T_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}$ in this new basis. Let $T'= \begin{pmatrix} T_{2,2}  & \dots & T_{2,n}  \\  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots 
 \\ T_{n,2} & \dots &  T_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}$, it is easy to see that $T$ has eigenvector $w = 0v+\alpha_1w_1+...+\alpha_{n-1}w_{n-1}$ if and only $T'$ has eigenvector $w$ in the subspace of dimension $n-1$ generated by the $w_i$ (for some eigenvalue $\lambda$). Therefore $T'$ has all eigenvalues $0$ and by induction $T'$ is strict upper-triangular in some basis. Perform a coordinate change to that basis.

The proof is completed by proving the lemma

> **Lemma 2** Strict upper-triangularity implies nilpotent

By induction. Base case $n=1$ then $T= \begin{pmatrix}0\end{pmatrix}$ is nilpotent with exponent 1. Assume it true for $1,...,n-1$. Let $T= \begin{pmatrix}0 &T_{1,2}  & \dots & T_{1,n} \\ 0& 0  & \dots & T_{2,n}  \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots 
 \\ 0 & 0  & \dots &  0 \end{pmatrix}$. It is easy to see that this is equivalent to the condition

\begin{equation} j\leq i \implies T_{i,j} =0  \end{equation}

and therefore  therefore that \begin{equation} j  \leq i + 1 \implies (\forall k) \  T_{i,k}T_{k,j} =0 \end{equation} by taking cases:

- $k\leq i \implies T_{i,k}T_{k,j} = 0 T_{k,j}= 0$
- $k>i  \implies k\geq i+1 \geq j  \implies  T_{i,k}T_{k,j} =T_{i,k} 0 = 0$

and therefore \begin{equation}j  \leq i + 1 \implies   T^2_{i,j} = \sum_kT_{i,k}T_{k,j} = 0 .\end{equation} Therefore we have that $T^2= \begin{pmatrix}0_{1 \times n-1} &T'  
 \\ 0 & 0_{n-1 \times 1}   \end{pmatrix}$ where $T'$ is strict upper-triangular. Let $k$ be the witness to the strict upper-triangularity, *i.e.* $(T')^{k}=0,$ then it is easy to see that $T^{2k} = 0$. **QED**